# Networks block in docker-composer

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to use ENV variable as a part of network name in docker-compose.yml? I tried something like this:

```
networks:
  ${PROJECT}-network:
     driver: bridge
```

I have .env file, which uses in build, I successfully extended ports etc. but network name is too hard for me(( Any suggestions?

Comment: When Compose creates underlying Docker objects, it usually qualifies them with its own notion of a project name, by default the name of the current directory; you don't need to also include that name in the Compose file.  Can you give a more complete example of where you need to override `${PROJECT}` like this within a single Compose file?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have same code for few projects on one physical server. I want change `.env` and start docker-compose. It should create new project with its own network and this project should listen ports provided in env. A have `traefic`, which route traffic to configured ports

Comment: Does setting [`$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) meet your needs?  (Or, equivalently, making sure each project is in a differently-named directory?)